# Escaping in eval's argument

Tags: javascript

I'm using `eval` to assign dynamic object's properties.

```
property_name_1 = property1;
property_name_2 = property2;
property_value_1 = 1;
property_value_2 = 2;
var obj = new Object;

eval("obj."+property_name_1+"='"+property_value_1+"'");
eval("obj."+property_name_2+"='"+property_value_2+"'");
```

then I'm using this object as post data during ajax request.

Everything is ok, but as well known eval is not safe function and I should escape `property_value_1`, `property_value_2`. For example, `property_value_2 = "<a href=''>Yahoo!</a>"` will cause error.

What is the best way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to not use `eval` at all:

```
obj[property_name_1] = property_value_1;
obj[property_name_2] = property_value_2;
```

If you still want to, you have to escape apostrophes and backslashes to put the values in string literals:

```
eval("obj." + property_name_1 + "='" + property_value_1.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\').replace(/'/g,"\\'") + "'");
eval("obj." + property_name_2 + "='" + property_value_2.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\').replace(/'/g,"\\'") + "'");
```

(If you surround the literal string with quotation marks instead of apostrophes, you have to escape quotation marks and backslashes.)

Answer (score 0):

Is `eval` really needed?

Based on your example you could simply do:

```
obj[property_name_1] = property_value_1;
obj[property_name_2] = property_value_2;
```

If this isn't a solution for you for whatever reason, go on about escaping quotes with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj[property_name] = property_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for completeness there is an extra answer not considered before.

With modern JS you can create an object similarly to what @Kalinin wanted to do, but with the desired result (note the `[]` around properties names):

```
var obj = {
    [property_name_1]: property_value_1, 
    [property_name_2]: property_value_2
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the object literal:

```
var obj = {
    property_name_1: property_value_1, 
    property_name_2: property_value_2
};
```

Comment: property_name_1 and 2 are clearly variables, but with an object literal declaration like above, the object keys will *literally* be the strings "property_name_1" and "property_name_2". In fact, there's no difference between this and `var obj = {"property_name_1": property_value_1, "property_name_2": property_value_1}`

Comment: This is something I learned the hard way... you need to use obj[property_name_1] syntax